# Variables not setting between cases?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
Dim StartBox As Long
Dim StartBox2 As Long


Select Case UCase(Target.Value)


Case "NEW-BOX"
    StartBox = ActiveCell.Row
    StartBox2 = ActiveCell.Column
    MsgBox (StartBox)
    MsgBox (StartBox2)
    Selection.Offset(-1, 2).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Activate
    Selection.Offset(1, -2).Select

Case "RESTART-BOX"
    MsgBox (StartBox)
    MsgBox (StartBox2)

   If StartBox = 0 And StartBox2 = 0 Then
MsgBox "Cannot restart box without scanning a new box first!", vbCritical
ElseIf StartBox <> 0 And StartBox2 <> 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(StartBox, StartBox2), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column)).ClearContents
End If


 End Select

End Sub
```

I scan a new box, and the variables set to the correct columns and row, but when I scan restart box, the message boxes both come up 0? Why is this? I need to pass these variables onto my code to clear the contents, but for some reason even though I am setting them they won't appear in 'RESTART-BOX' ?

Comment: In your if statements at the bottom there, you appear to be using `+` to mean "and". I've just tried it and the behaviour is probably not what you expect. Replace them with the literal string `and`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "restart box". If you are not setting the 2 variables before your select statement you'll get 0 every time. Please can you post more code.

Comment: @Vicky Thank you, I have corrected this, however I still have the problem with the variables.

Comment: @glh I have updated my code to reflect this, I am not setting the variables before the select statement, however if I cannot set the variables in this specific case I don't know how else to clear the contents.

Comment: @SamCousins if it's necessary to set the variables **within** the case, you will have to set the variables within **each** case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need more context to be able to provide a definitive answer. Is your code in a loop of some sort or is this a sub or function being called multiple times?

If the latter then you will get a new copy of StartBox and StartBox2 created each time you call the sub / function, so they won't retain the values. If you place the `dim` statements outside the sub or function then they will become global variables and will retain their values across each call to the sub or function.

Comment: I have updated my code to provide more detail, I am not setting the variables before the select statement, however if I cannot set the variables in this specific case I don't know how else to clear the contents.

EDIT:
After testing, setting the variables as global did in fact work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your 2 variables before your select statement:

```
...

StartBox = ActiveCell.Row
StartBox2 = ActiveCell.Column

Select Case UCase(Target.Value)

...
```